# How do Dambadiva kings fit in Indian history?

Tags: buddhism, indian

My question, I would like to know whether any space in Indian history to fit Dambadiva  kings in Indian history rather than keeping them only in Buddhist books? or it feels like they were foreign kings?

By leaving behind many number of books in original Mahavanshaya which were written in the past history by covering all 29th Lord Buddha's eras and the Great emperors in the great Island including King Maha Sammatha, King Ravana, King Shaka generation (King Shaka 1 to King Shaka 15) and many more Great emperors' eras, Mahavanshaya was rewritten by native foreigner, Monk Mahanama with influence of foreigner, Monk Buddhagosha in 05th Century.

As per the known history rewritten Mahavanshaya was not even  completed by those two foreigners based on protest which was arisen among the locals by leading Monk Upathissa, and also those two monks had left the island secretly by leaving incomplete rewritten Mahavanshaya in the Island.
Native foreigner, Monk Mahanama has taken the start in rewritten Mahavanshaya by giving all 29 Lord Buddhas’ era with simple introduction by giving a clue of foreign arrivals, and  further stating there are many books of Mahavanshaya which ware already written in the past history by locals about the history of the island, however due to there are many errors in the written history, he rewrites the history of the Island by making short its long stories and dragging short stories to long stories by adding taste of art in to the history.
Here there is a BIG question?  How foreigner cut long stories to short stories in foreign country history? How he says there were many errors in the written history of the Island which was led to more than 20 thousand year's history by covering all 29 Lord Buddha's eras.
Native Foreigner,author of Mahavanshaya, has made many effort to convince readers to believe Dambadiva is a foreign  place in another country without mentioning the country. However in ancient written even in foreign countries, there are many evidence to proof it is the island of Jambudeepa, and also it was Heladeepa, Three Sinhale, Sinhale, Ceylon and SriLanka. Below are the few great examples to prove  Dambadiva is not a foreign place in another country, it is the Island of Ceylon.

First three  evidence ware taken from a great history book which was recently written in native language with heard research  under title "Land of Lord Buddha"   It was written by Mr H.S.Herath
1st Evidence - "General Account of the Encircling Ocean" this is also known as  "Ying-hwin-che-ke"
This book was written by yin Huwan -che-ke,  Lieutenant of Fue Kien reigon in 04th Century
In a chapter it says
"Seih-lan is situated in Southern India, and is a large island in the sea, on the south east ,coast,its circumference been about 1000 le (300 miles) having in the centre lofty mountains ;on the coast the land in low and marshy . The country is characterised by much rain and constant thunder. The hills and valleys are beautifully ornamented with flowers and trees of great variety and beauty, the cries of animals rejoicing together fill the air with gladness,and the landscape abounds with splendour.  In the forests are many elephants and the native use them instead of draught oxen or horses.  The people are all of the Buddhist religion ;it is said that Buddha was born here....

2nd Evidence-

Huu Newil book collection in London Museum-6607(2) - "Three Sinhale Kadaim saha Viththi " this book was written in native language in SriLanka, author A.J.W Marabe
"Magam paththuve Thissa maha veheraya pihita vadalau desiya dolahak magul lakunu athi saman deviyange aradanaven me jambuddeepaye senaga vadapuda gaththau samantha kuta parvathayada yana meki sthanada ruhunu ratata athulath vanneya"

English translation:

(This Island was also called “three Sinhale” one period of ancient time based on 03 monarchs in the Island)

Title of the book: “Three Sinhale boundaries and description” (ancient palm tree written book)

In a paragraph, author further explained quoting below information to indicate boundaries in the monarch of Ruhuna saying

“Thissa Dagaba in division of Magam, and Saman Mountain with 212 fortune symbols which is worshiped by here locals in Jambudeepa with an invitation of God Saman are also included to the Monarch of Ruhuna”

This ancient palm tree written book  is old nearly 700 years.

Mountain Saman  is also known as Sripada mountain which is situated in SriLanka, Buddhist worship this mountain based on Lord Buddha's footprint on it

03rd evidence:

In an ancient book under title “Wanni Rajavaliya” Author, A.V Suraweera
In  page 70, in a poem,  author explained incident which was occurred in SriLanka in native language saying
Ape muni varshayen lath hathsiya visithunaka
Ai  Baminisaya Dabadiva pamini warshayaka
Dakamin ekak Dabadiva rajakala warshayaka
Palabu thilovata mathu saka varshayaka

English translation:

In our Lord Buddha’s calendar years, year, seven hundred and three
Year, Baminisaya Drought was in Dambadiva
Year, viewing one, being in crown
Shine Lord Buddha in future Shaka year

As a known history, Baminisaya Drought was a well-known drought in SriLanka in ancient time, and also Shaka warsha/shaka years were generated in one of the King Shaka era in king Shaka generation  in SriLanka, ancient time, as per the history which were read by Dr. Mirando Obesekara  in ancient palm written book, there were 15 kings in King Shaka generation as King Shaka 1 to King Shaka  15

Further There was a conflict between  Abayagiri Vihara monks & Maha vihara monks during the period of King Prakkamabahu 1, and this era(12th century CE), pure Theravada Buddhism was in threat,and Abayagiri Vihara was struggling to protect the pure Theravada Buddhism and the  Great history of the island which was bound  with Buddhism more than   20 thousand year's  history which was led to  29 Load Buddha's eras including Lord Buddha, Kakusada , Lord Buddha Konagama, Lord Buddha Kashshapa and Lord Buddha Gothama and finally as Abayagiri Vihara monks made a genuine  effort to protect the Island even forcing to king Prakkamabahu 1 to  give up his throne  to protect the pure Theravada Buddhism in the Island  from the King, who was no interest to hold his due responsibility  to protect  the Theravada Buddhism through his  crown; they were defeated by the Kind together with monks in  Maha vihara who influence foreign involvements to decline the pure Theravada Buddhism in the kingdom Not only that as per the known history, the history books which were stored   in  Abayagiri vihara library  about Great history of the Island with  more than 20 thousand year's history ware burned after Abayagiri Vihara was defeated by  the King and the Monks in Maha vihara, as per the known history the books were on the floor  up to the  height of seven elephants if they were on, one another when  books were caught  fire.

Monk Mahanama not only misled Dambadiva History, Island Ceylon, but also Indian History by dragging foreign country history, and mixing it in to their history, hence Dambadiva kings are in only in Buddhist books in Indian history.

Comment: Can you please name the "_Dambadiva kings_"? And it _seems_ to me you're particularly interested in _history of Theravada Buddhism_ - is this area of focus?

Answer (score -1):

The word **Dambadiva** does not fit into Indian history because the reference is wrong. It does not refer to anything in India.

The word "Dambadiva" is the Sinhala translation of the Pali term Jambudipa. The name is wrongly used to refer to India/Nepal where Buddha lived. Check the Google search here -> https://www.google.com/search?q=dambadiva

Dambadiva is in fact the "Deva Area" shown here.

[image]

How the history got distorted is mentioned here -> https://jambudipa.quora.com